# Redirecting the user to a sub

Tags: python

So I've been coding in VB.net but now recently started coding python on the side. One of the features in VB is to redirect the user to a new sub. This is what i have tried

```
def option1():
    print ("opt1")


def option2():
    print ("opt2")


def option3():
    print ("opt3")


UserOp = input("What option would you like to do? 1, 2 or 3 : ")

if UserOp == "1":
    option1()

elif UserOp == "2":
    option2()

elif UserOp == "3":
    option3()
```

So the goal here is to try and redirect the user to the designated 'def' depending on which option they chose. This code has no errors. But doesn't actually redirect the user to the def.

thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. I run it, enter "1" and it prints "opt1". What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: What is the behavior you are expecting to see?

Comment: If you are using `python2.7`, please try to change `input` to `raw_input`

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell when you receive `2` you want it to print

```
opt2
opt3
```

The issue is that functions do not move to a point in the script, they execute the instructions where you call them.
I'd recommend that you include the functionality you want around the if statements.
Try this code:

```py
while True:
UserOp = input("What option would you like to do? 1, 2 or 3 : ")

    if UserOp == "1":
        print('opt1')

    elif UserOp == "2":
        print('opt1', 'opt2')

    elif UserOp == "3":
        print('opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3')
```

If I misread your question, I'm sorry to say this, but it was unclear.

Comment: I think it's honorable that you want to help, but your effort is wasted here. The Q is three years old and indeed lacks fundamental info, as you noticed, so I'd rather say it can be closed.